# Temporarily increase limits for .set ingest query in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, limit, azure-data-explorer

We need to initially import and transform large amounts of data in Azure Data Explorer.

The transformation consists of several .set operations containing queries representing transformational steps.

When i run those queries, they exeed [certain limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits) ADX imposes to protect the cluster.

The error message is

> aggregation over string column exceeded the memory budget of 8GB
> during evaluation

I know i can override those default limits for memory consumption [per iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-memory-per-iterator) and [per node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-memory-per-node) but this seems to only work for queries without ingestion commands.

When i want to run

```
set max_memory_consumption_per_query_per_node=68719476736;
.set async DestinationTable <| SourceTable | ...
```

ADX complains with

> The incomplete fragment is unexpected.

Is there a way to temporarily increase those query limits for .set-ingest operations as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit you're hitting isn't configurable using the options you included above.

The best approach would be optimizing the query/command you're running - you can start with [query best practices](https://aka.ms/kusto.query-best-practices) and considering splitting the single `.set-or-append` command into multiple ones (see "Remarks" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query)).

If these still don't help, I would recommend that you include the full command text here for further advice.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah i went down the approach of splitting the result into multiple subsets but i think in the end the main culprit was, that the query contained a join and the large table was on the left hand side.